# How to remove insert image button from Yahoo Rich text editor

Tags: javascript, image, thickbox, yahoo-widgets

I am using ThickBox 3.1 one one page. 
Now, there is one problem, 
i am using one form to open thickbox on the button click event. 
And i am using yahoo text editor on that form. 
And in the yahoo rich text editor there is one link of image insert.. but i don't know why its not opening. on click of it. the image insert dialog is not opening. 
all things are working properly. 
Why is it not opening? 
 and if is there anyway to only remove the image insert icon from text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, if you change setting on buttons block by removing **insertimage**

from

```
buttons: [ 
     { type: 'push', label: 'HTML Link CTRL + SHIFT + L', value: 'createlink', disabled: true }, 
     { type: 'push', label: 'Insert Image', value: 'insertimage' } 
]
```

to

```
buttons: [ 
     { type: 'push', label: 'HTML Link CTRL + SHIFT + L', value: 'createlink', disabled: true }
]
```

ref: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/toolbar_editor.html

Comment: var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('msgpost', {
            height: '300px',
            width: '518px',
            dompath: true, //Turns on the bar at the bottom
            animate: true //Animates the opening, closing and moving of Editor windows
         });
        myEditor.render();

//i am rendering by this style.
so can you tell me..to only remove the insertimage button.
thanks for your replay.